# CREATE a new text file ONLY - php

Tags: php, file, text, upload, server-side

I was wondering whether it was possible to allow users the ability to upload a empty text file to the server?

Concept: Visit site, are given a input field - you input your existing text file if already on the server (done this).. If you want to create a file and upload to server, input its name and press a submit button which then creates a blank file which can then be used in the first field (existing text file) (LIMITED to .txt files only)

Is this possible, if so.. where do i even start! o

Comment: Yes it is possible. Try [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)

Comment: Could you maybe run me through an answer, as i've seen that but don't quite understand what is needed.

Comment: Basic concept `$_POST['variable'] = ""; $file = "TEST.txt"; file_put_contents($file, $_POST['variable']);` which will create a file called `TEST.txt` with nothing in it.

Comment: So would i have a button that redirects to a page with that code?

Comment: You would create a form according to the POST variable. I.e: `<input type="text" name="variable">` then use a conditional statement based on what the user wants to do / (*in a nutshell*)